# MySQL select extra column if date is in future

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check whether my `date` field is in the future using MySQL and if so, add an extra column.  It's important that I do not want to make this part of my where clause as I want to return rows where the `date` field is not in the future.

For example:

```
select 
    dateIsInFuture = 'true' if date > now()
```

I know the above is not valid syntax but I need to know how to write that in a valid SQL statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
select *, case when date_col > now() 
               then 'true'
               else 'false'
          end as dateIsInFututre
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), but using this syntax:

```
SELECT IF(date > now(), 'true', 'false') as FutureFlag FROM YOUR_TABLE
```